# How do I fix my table so that the columns don't expand on re-sizing of the window?

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I have the following HTML table and associated CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/67LE7/

I believe this is the CSS that is causing the problem

```
.content {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 944px;
      min-width: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;    
}
```

When I expand the Result window horizontally, the first column expands infinitely and pushes the second and third columns to the next row. The intended result is for all three columns to maintain a fixed size and appear on the same row. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a fixed width pricing table and remove the media queries.  The media queries are resetting the widths.  The media queries will make it look nice on phones and tablets, but if you do not need that...

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67LE7/1/)

```
.pricing-table{
    width: 150px;

/*@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .pricing-table{
        width: 48.9%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .pricing-table{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The funny thing is that it looks even worse on phones and tablets. I will try and upload the code to a server later tonight so you can see what I mean.